# WaitForMultipleObjects with an array of CWinThread pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mfc

I have a loop generating threads via `AfxBeginThread`, which stores the `CWinThread` pointers in an array. In each iteration, I check the thread is not null and store the thread's handle in another array.

```
const unsigned int maxThreads = 2;
CWinThread* threads[maxThreads];
HANDLE* handles[maxThreads];
for(unsigned int threadId=0; threadId < maxThreads; ++threadId)
{
    threads[threadId] = AfxBeginThread(endToEndProc, &threadId,
                                            0,0,CREATE_SUSPENDED);
    if(threads[threadId] == NULL) 
    {
        // die carefully
    }
    threads[threadId]->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
    handles[threadId] = &threads[threadId]->m_hThread;
    ::ResumeThread(handles[threadId]);
}

DWORD result = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(maxThreads, handles[0], 
                                            TRUE, 20000*maxThreads);
```

But `WaitForMultipleObjects` always returns with `WAIT_FAILED`, and `GetLastError` yields `6` for invalid handle. Either the test for the `AfxBeginThread` return is insufficient to guarantee the thread was created successfully and the handle will be valid, or the handle is becoming invalid before the WaitForMultipleObjects call, which I thought would be prevented by setting `m_bAutoDelete` to `FALSE`.

Is there a better way to wait on multiple threads when they are created by `AfxBeginThread`?

Note that it is fine when `maxThreads=1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`handles[0]` points to something that has ONE valid handle and some data possibly following it. `maxThreads` instead suggests that array should have two handles there one after another. Hence the error.

This is what you want instead:

```
HANDLE handles[maxThreads];
//...
handles[threadId] = threads[threadId]->m_hThread;
//...
WaitForMultipleObjects(maxThreads, handles, ...
```

Comment: Ahhh, got it. Arrays of pointers to handles bad, pointer to array of handles good. Thank you very much.